# Does a react component using useState hook rerender every `setState` call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

https://codesandbox.io/s/mow5zl5729

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function useLoading() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [hasError, setError] = React.useState(false);

  const loadStuff = aPromise => {
    return aPromise
      .then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(true);
      });
  };

  return { isLoading, hasError, loadStuff };
}

function App() {
  const { isLoading, hasError, loadStuff } = useLoading();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadStuff(axios.get(`https://google.com`));
  }, []);

  console.log(isLoading, hasError);

  return <div />;
}
```

This is a simplified example of what I mean.

If the promise inside `useLoading` is rejected, I would have expected the component to render on mount and then render the second time when the error is caught. So, I expect a total of 2 renders with the following state:

1st render:

- isLoading: true
- hasError: false

2nd render:

- isLoading: false
- hasError: true

Instead, it seems that the component rerenders once after `setLoading(false)` and again after `setError(true)`. So, I get this:

1st render:

- isLoading: true
- hasError: false

2nd render: **( why? )**

- isLoading: false
- hasError: false

3rd render:

- isLoading: false
- hasError: true

I suspect that the issue is somehow my use of the promise inside `useEffect` but I'm not sure where my mental model went wrong.

EDIT:

When I change `useLoading` to only contain 1 `useState`, the problem goes away.

broken:

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
const [hasError, setError] = React.useState(false);
```

works:

```
const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = React.useState({
  loading: true,
  error: false
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this has something to do with batching of the state updates. As far as I know React based events will trigger the batch updates but not something that gets triggered outside it. `promise` in this case.

Because the state calls are not batched, you see the `2nd render` where both are set to false

Comment: You're right! This comment makes it clear: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-439632622

I must have never noticed that because in class components, I pretty much always collapsed `setState` calls into one that returns the whole new state.